# Restful route design for adding item to container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

My cart can have many folders. Those can be nested, but are always displayed as a whole. I want to design an interface to add new item to the folder.

My plan is to have a button for folder, after clicking it, the products#index is displayed. The user select one product, and in the products#show page, the user fills some options and click submit, then the item is added into the particular folder.

What's a RESTful way to design the routes?

My rough design is the following. Is it okay?

```
get folders/13/add_products/ 
get folders/13/add_products/3 
post folders/13/add_products/3
```

Comment: using verbs like add_products is not too restful, if you want to create products into folders you can do a post request to folders/<folderid>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should avoid verbs (e.g. "add") in RESTful routes:

```
GET  /folders/:id/products
GET  /folders/:id/products/:product_id
POST /folders/:id/products/:product_id
```

Comment: Didn't know that thanks. So POST /folders/:id/products/:product_id instead of POST /folders/:id/products/ (like common create routes)?

Comment: Yes, at least if it's possible for a product to be in multiple folders at the same time. If not, you should probably use "PUT /products/:id".